# Convert mathematical formula to image locally on Linux

Tags: linux, latex, png

Looking for a way to produce .pngs or similar of mathematical formulas locally, for use in documents and presentations.

There are [plenty of online tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115459/online-tool-for-generating-mathematical-equation-image-files), but I was hoping for a tool I can use from the command line, with no internet connection.

If there is a way to do this with Latex, that's a valid solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sam Carter's](https://superuser.com/users/383391/samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz) answer prompted a [discussion in the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112573/discussion-between-young-souvlaki-and-samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz). This is the source of the latex code and permissions fix in this answer.

.tex file:

```latex
\documentclass[convert={density=500}, border=2pt, varwidth=8in]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
_{256}P_{8} = \frac{256!}{(256 - 8)!} = 1.65 \times 10^{19}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

`density` increases the resolution.

`border` leaves room so content is not cut off by document edges.

`varwidth` allows you to use `align`. I set it to standard A4 page width and take care of the trimming in my bash function below.

Bash function:

```sh
latex2png()
{
    pdflatex --shell-escape "$1"
    convert -trim ${1/tex/png} ${1/tex/png}  # trims border to content
    trash *pdf *aux *log  # alias I made as a safe rm; careful not to delete other pdfs!
}
```

Because I include the cleanup line, I make sure all my .tex files are in a separate directory. `latex2png` is a package that might be on your system; consider renaming.

If you get a permissions error see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998331/imagemagick-security-policy-pdf-blocking-conversion) as mentioned in the [discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112573/discussion-between-young-souvlaki-and-samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz).
Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998331/imagemagick-security-policy-pdf-blocking-conversion/58438910#58438910) for arch.

Use:

```sh
latex2png permutation.tex
```

.png output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standalone class:

```
\documentclass[convert=true]{standalone}

\begin{document}

$E=mc^2$

\end{document}
```

[image]

(needs to be compiled with shell-escape enabled for the conversion to png)

Comment: Can you show an example compile command?

Comment: @young_souvlaki `pdflatex --shell-escape filename`

Comment: Thanks. That converts to pdf and cuts off some of the bottom and top edges. I was looking for a conversion directly to png

Comment: This automatically converts the pdf to png. Do you get any warning/errors?

Comment: When I run the compile command on my `.tex` it outputs `.log`, `.aux`, and `.pdf`. No `.png`.

Comment: any warnings/errors in the terminal?

Comment: Ah! Good call there was an error: 
`:convert: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy gs' @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/378. convert: no images defined 'key.png' @ error/convert.c  /ConvertImageCommand/3285. system returned with code 256`

Comment: Can you manually test if `convert key.pdf key.png` works?

Comment: and please show the first couple of lines of your .log file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112573/discussion-between-young-souvlaki-and-samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz).